# setting color of label at runtime in flex and actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, label

I would like to assign color to a label text at run time and I am not sure how to do that.

I have a MXML file that has the label component

```
<mp:Table
                        id="table"
                        dataProvider="{model.datatable}"
                        title="">
                    <mp:columns>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name">
                            <mx:itemRenderer>
                                <mx:Component>

                                    <mx:Label color="{data.color}" toolTip="{data.toolTip}" text="{data.name}" textAlign="left" textDecoration="underline"
                                              buttonMode="true" click=""/>
                                </mx:Component>
                            </mx:itemRenderer>
                        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Addresses" dataField="addresses" width="200"/>

                    </mp:columns>
                </mp:Table>
```

I have a separate as(actionscript file) where I populate the datatable array collection.
I set the value of color in the array collection and use it to display the label in the MXML file. It doesn't seem to work.

I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not really a flex user, but I think you just need to use the `setStyle` method - eg  `myLabel.setStyle("color",0xFF0000);`

Comment: @Batman You can set set styles in MXML as shown above (`color="{data.color}"`). If the OP was applying the color in Actionscript, then he would need to use `setStyle()`.

Comment: Your code looks OK on the surface. Do you see any evidence of the item renderer working? E.g. is the text of the label being displayed? Maybe you should show us an example of your data...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a bindable "data.color" you should be able to change the label color by simply changing data.color to something else. If that doesn't work you can still use setStyle (but the label should have a defined id):

```
mylabel.setStyle("color", 0xFF0000);
```

Comment: I set the color attribute in the array collection datatable in the actionscript file like, datatable.color="#003399". but it doesnt work. I dont know how to reference the label in actionscript file, while the label is declared in the MXML file

Comment: all flex components have a id attribute. Declare that id attribute. You do it for table: id="table" so why can't you do it for the label?

Comment: Yes I declared an id for the attribute and referenced it from the function in the actionscript file and didnt work.

Comment: @ShenoyTinny when you set the color in code (as opposed to setting it in MXML) you have to specify it has a hex number by prefixing it with `0x` instead of `#`. Use: `data.color = 0x003399` The same way BotMaster is doing it above in the `setStyle()` example.

Comment: @ShenoyTinny - Yes, do it like the code shown,  or rather I should say like the code I showed in my comment on your question...

Comment: "like the code I showed in my comment on your question" which is just a copy and paste of what I showed, You did not even bother changing the 'myLabel'. what is wrong with you?